# x509 certificate not valid for any names when added IP address to openssl.cnf

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, self-signed-certificate, x509, subject-alternative-names

A self-signed certificate works well while the command used to generate it on a ubuntu machine is:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout private.key -out cert.crt -days 365 -nodes
```

If the client side uses an IP address instead of the domain name, it would fail.

To make the IP address working, following the instructions from [this previous question and answer about failed handshake due to not containing any IP SANs](https://serverfault.com/questions/611120/failed-tls-handshake-does-not-contain-any-ip-sans), the `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` is modified to have the `subjectAltName = IP:192.168.2.107` added to the `[v3_ca]` section.

This change makes the IP address work well, however the domain name does not work anymore. The error message is:

```
x509: certificate is not valid for any names, but wanted to match yoursubdomain.yourdomain.com
```

[Another source about SANs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sssd-ldap-domain-ip) basically is suggesting the same without a clear hint how to make both IP address and DNS work at the same time.

How to have both IP address and domain name work together?

Comment: add the DNS names like in the answer [here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488845/how-can-i-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-with-subjectaltname-using-openssl)

Comment: So: [1] instead of `subjectAltName=192.168.2.107`, change to `subjectAltName = @alternate_names`. [2] add a section `[ alternate_names ]`. [3] list IP address below it as `IP.1 = 192.168.2.207`, and DNS as `DNS.1 = subdomain.domain.com`. will give that a try. do you want put that into an answer?

Comment: were you able to get the cert as wanted? I can recommend XCA a cross platform certificate manager if you want to play with certificates.

Comment: Nice! https://github.com/chris2511/xca/ and https://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/

Comment: Maybe also multiple subjects in one line like `subjectAltName_default = DNS:myhost.com.au,IP:127.0.0.1,EMAIL:my@here.org` as suggested by https://serverfault.com/questions/455525/openssl-how-to-generate-a-csr-with-interactively-solicited-subject-alternative